# Unable to locate element as ID changes after refreshing the in Ebay login page

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, junit

Using JUnit I'm attempting to automate the eBay login. I cannot select the email/username field because field changes id on refresh. Any ideas?

```
input size="40" maxlength="64" name="962970435" id="962970435" type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" placeholder="Email or username" class="fld"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following XPath should work:

```
//input[@placeholder='Email or username'][@type='text']
```

Comment: I just verified. This xpath worked.

Comment: just added [@type='text'] because were 2 results and worked like a charm. Great thanks. 

(//input[@type='text'][@placeholder='Email or username'])

Comment: @mdriver You're version is better. I've updated my answer since this version is more explicit and doesn't need indexing.

Comment: Xpath is flaky, might break after trivial design change. CSS based locator suggested by @Michael Durrant is much more reliable.

Comment: @Peter What makes this XPath any more "flaky" than the equivalent CSS locator?

Comment: After trivial redesign, XPath breaks. CSS is likely to be more stable because it is also used to style the page. Of course CSS if flaky too, best is ID or name.

Comment: That doesn't really hold. if you use the equivalent XPath and it breaks, the CSS would also break.

Answer (score 3):

If 'ID' of your webElement changes everytime after refreshing the page in this situation:

**First of all look for any other attribute which Is not changing every time In that div node like name, class etc.**

**Option 1:** If this div node has class, name attribute then you can write XPath as below.

```
//input[@class='fld']
OR
//input[@type='text'][@class='fld']
OR
//input[@name='962970435']
```

**Option 2:** You can use the starts-with function.

```
 //input[starts-with(@placeholder,'Email or username')]
```

**Option 3:** You can use contains function. Same way you can use contains function as given below.

```
 //input[contains(@class,'fld')]
 //input[contains(@type,'text')]
```

Comment: Let me know if it works for you...

Comment: Thought on options 2 and 3, too, but are not applicable for my example because id number changes randomly.

(//input[@type='text'][@placeholder='Email or username']) 
found out that works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer css selectors:

```
input[placeholder='Email or username'][type=text]
```

Also, I'd prefer to scope to the login form, e.g.

```
form#SignInForm input[placeholder~='[E|e]mail'][type=text]
```

You may need to scope further with

```
form#SignInForm div#pri_signin input[placeholder~='[E|e]mail'][type=text]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either CSS Selector or Xpath.
As CSS selector is already discussed above, let me point out how i achieved this using Xpath.

To identify , we will have to use a combination of 2 elements separated by AND operator as below.

Xpath : //input[@placeholder='Email or username' AND @type='text']

Hope this helps!
Asky